# Do LLM crawlers respect the robots meta tag?

Tags: meta-tags, robots.txt, large-language-model

It is currently possible to use `robots.txt` to [disallow](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2023/12/no-robotstxt-how-ask-chatgpt-and-google-bard-not-use-your-website-training?) [Large Language Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) crawlers via user-agent strings:

```
User-agent: GPTBot
Disallow: /
```

But this approach is very broad and while it works for site administrators, it wouldn't allow users of a CMS, for example, to opt out on a per account basis.

I'm trying to understand if it's possible to use the robots meta tag, for a more granular permission, for example:

`<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

Also do the LLM crawlers even use `noindex` as an opt-out, or is there a new meta-content-keyword to use? for example `noteach`, or `nolearn`.

Comment: They aren't creating a search index, so my guess is that `noindex` would not even be applicable in this case.